# how can I do a clear icon inside a circle

Tags: svg

Hi everyone I want to make a delete Button that when I press it until the result will come back it spins and then when I got the right response make it Green with checkmark inside (I make it already) but when I get that I miss fields I want to get a red circle with Cancel Icon inside.
I don't really good in SVG yet and I would like your help
the code bellow this is the SVG I made after search on the internet
but I Searched a lot of time the Cancel Icon and couldn't find anything that fit what I Need

```
<svg width="84px" height="84px" viewBox="0 0 84 84" version="1.1">
   <circle className="border" cx="42" cy="42" r="40" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" fill="none"></circle>
   <path className="checkmark" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M23.375 42.5488281 36.8840688 56.0578969 64.891932 28.0500338" stroke-width="4" stroke="green" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

the closest thing I could make is this:

[image: cancer l inside circle]

I would like the cancel sign to be in the middle

Comment: Learn the SVG path commands: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shows you have used **stroke="greem"** instead of **stroke="green"** in path tag.

```html
<svg width="84px" height="84px" viewBox="0 0 84 84" version="1.1">
   <circle className="border" cx="42" cy="42" r="40" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" fill="none"></circle>
   <path className="checkmark" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M30 55 55 30 M30 30 55 55" stroke-width="4" stroke="green" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I want to do it the same with cancel or close icon

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk edited my code snippet. Please check if it solves your requirement